# Tagging People in Actions

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-opengraph

[It is possible to tag people in open graph actions.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople)

Now my question:

As an example I have the action "watch a movie". When I tag a friend in this action does this mean that he/she also see this movie?

Gets my friend also the aggregation "movies I saw" in his/her timeline with the same movie?

Answer (score 0):

When you tag a user in an action instance (by posting 'tags=UID1,UID2' etc - its like you're saying they did the action with you. This means it appears on their timeline like they did it. Think of it like tagging friends in a checkin.

You must only tag a user in an action if they really did the action with you too. This channel is closely monitored for abuse. If you tag users and they reject that tag, you'll app will be penalised.

Comment: Hi Simon, we met us in Berlin this year :-)

"This means it appears on their timeline like they did it."

Does this mean, does he/she get also the aggregation in her/his timeline?

Comment: I've tested it and it seems to be not quite the same.
You're right, it looks like they did it but they don't get the object in their aggregation.
But I think if they did it they should also get the object in their aggregation.